# Field Collection no respond

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-field-collection

my Drupal field collection having a no respond issue after I created 3 fields using field collection and try to add more.

Edit a page or create new page also have the same issue. Can't add more than 3 fields.

Double checked the setting in content type field, set to "unlimited" values for the field.

The blue loading icon just keep load for few minutes and nothing happens.

SS: http://imageshack.com/a/img34/3180/hc5u.png

The system is

Drupal 7.26

PHP 5.2.17 (tried max_input_vars in php.ini/.htaccess but not working)

Field Collection 7.x-1.0-beta5

There are only 3 fields in the field collection: a Boolean, 2 long text fields.

Comment: Requirement of Drupal 7 take from https://drupal.org/requirements `Drupal 7: PHP 5.2.5 or higher (5.3 recommended)`. Could you try on php 5.3 and see if it still exists?

Comment: 5.2.17 is higher than 5.2.5, others website hosted on the same server works well.Tested and found out that if the CKEditor reach number of 5 in a creation page, an ajax error occurred. HTTP code:403.

Comment: @D34dman here's a SS on Network result. http://imageshack.com/a/img197/9905/rfft.png